# Collection fetch doesnt fire reset

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I am just going crazy as why is this not working. I have a collection that fetches the data. The collection is bind to run render function on reset. But render isnt called.

```
this.uploadTemplate = _.template(UploadTemplate);
this.artistCollection = new ArtistCollections();
this.artistCollection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
this.artistCollection.fetch({success: function(){console.log('jsjbajsb');},
      error: function(collection, response, options){ console.log(response)}});
// this.artistCollection.fetch({reset: true});
this.me = options.me;
```

Neither is the success function called nor the commented line works

### Edit :1 Added error option

Comment: Have you tried adding an error callback? Any errors in your server logs or the JavaScript console? Have you examined the server's response in your browser's developer tools to see if anything is amiss?

Comment: Does your collection have a [`url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url)? Is it correct? Does the server get contacted at all? Does it receive the parameters that it is expecting? Does it send back the right data in the right format?

Comment: ok , I added the error option, its logging the response. but how to see the error. I mean the status is 200.

Comment: Check in your browser's developer tools to see what the server is sending back (both the raw data and the content type).

Comment: the url is correct, the server is sending back json data. Response text shows "[{'id': 462, 'name': u'blah blah'},.....]"

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not sending a correct Json-fied response. Lots of thnks to @mu is too short.

I wish backbone would have provided a verbose error in this case.